# How to decompress the contents of a var to another var?

Tags: variables, compression, tcl, gzip, deflate

I'm trying to uncompress what's inside of a var into the same var or onto another.
I created a .gz file using gzip -k filename. It generated a filename.gz while keeping the original. I uploaded this gz file to a server.
The following line downloads the gz file to a var. Yes, I could use package require http, etc...

```
set testvar [exec wget -q -O - url-to-gz-file]; string length $testvar
```

The string length $testvar returns a number.
Now, I need to deflate/decompress what's inside of $testvar to the same var or to another var like testvar2 and this var has to contain the contents of the original file. I mean, the contents of the file before being compressed. The original file is just a text file.

I probably need to instruct that testvar is binary.

Is this possible? I do not want to download the .gz file first to the hard drive and process it after. It all needs to be done "in memory".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to just pipe `wget` into `gunzip`:

```
set result [exec wget -q -O - url-to-gz-file | gunzip -c]
```

This requires that the uncompressed contents be encoded in your system's default character encoding; if it's binary data or some other text encoding, you'll have problems (Your `teststr` variable probably isn't holding valid gzip data either because of the character encoding translation).

In those cases, tcl comes with the [`zlib` command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/zlib.htm) for working with zlib and gzip compression. The `zlib gunzip STRING` subcommand, in particular, would be useful here. You have to use [`open`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm) for that, not `exec`, in order to get binary data that can be passed to the `zlib gunzip`. It would look something like:

```
# b for opening in binary mode instead of having to set it with fconfigure
set wget [open "| wget -q -O - url-to-gz-file" rb]
set binData [zlib gunzip [read -nonewline $wget]]
close $wget
set result [encoding convertfrom utf-8 $binData] ;# Or whatever encoding the file uses
```

You can use `zlib push` to add a layer to the `wget` channel so that using `read` on it automatically decompresses the data too.

```
set wget [open "| wget -q -O - url-to-gz-file" rb]
zlib push gunzip $wget
set result [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [read -nonewline $wget]]
close $wget
```

Comment: You can combine the opening a pipeline with customizing the text encoding too.  There's More Than One Way To Do It is not just for perl.

Comment: Channel transforms act on the binary data side of the channel. You probably don't need the `encoding convertfrom` when using `zlib push gunzip`.

Comment: @DonalFellows I tested that one; it was needed.

Comment: Come to think, I wonder if `fconfigure -encoding` would do it.